# Facebook login button style

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have this code to display a login facebook button

```
<span style="float:right; height:40px; line-height:45px;vertical-align:top; 
font-size:14px; padding-right:10px; "><?php if($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
{    echo "Welcome " .anchor('profile',$this->tank_auth->get_username())." | ".anchor
    ('profile/find_friends','Find Friends')." | ".anchor('auth/logout','Logout');} 
   else {?><?php echo  anchor('auth/login','Login'); ?> | 
  <fb:login-button v="2" perms="" length="long" 
  onlogin='window.location="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<?php echo  
$this->config->item('facebook_app_id'); ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo site_ur
('auth_other/fb_signin'); ?>&amp;r="+window.location.href;'></fb:login-button><?php } ?></span>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

this code converts to this when I browse the page :

```
<fb:login-button v="2" perms="" length="long" 
   onlogin="window.location=&quot;https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize? 
   client_id=372198139465874&amp; 
  redirect_uri=http://allviralvideo.org/auth_other/fb_signin&amp;r=&quot;+window.location.href;" 
  login_text="" class=" fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-  
  query="app_id=372198139465874&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey">
  **<span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 69px; height: 22px; ">**<iframe 
  name="f1d6c3fee8" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" 
  scrolling="no" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" style="border-top-style: none; 
  border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: 
  initial; border-color: initial; width: 69px; height: 22px; visibility: visible; " 
  src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=372198139465874&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D28%23cb%3Df11db3306c%26domain%3Dallviralvideo.org%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fallviralvideo.org%252Ff72d2ade4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey" class=""></iframe></span></fb:login-button>
```

I want to remove vertical-align: bottom; from bold section. I added vertical-align: top; to parent tags but it suppresses them. Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: I think removeClass() method will help you when you use JavaScript. However I don't know so much JS. Sorry...

=(

Comment: I use these but nothing changed : <style>
.fb:login-button span {
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('fb:login-button:span').removeAttr('style');
    
});</style>

Comment: I add vertical-align: top !important; to fb:login-button. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the span in your CSS using whatever is the immediate parent of your Facebook button. Something like:

```
.parent span {
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

Since it's generating in-line styles, you'll need to use the !important or else it will be overridden.

you also be able to target the fb element directly in the CSS, but I've never worked with it so I can't be sure.